# DB2 Query Timeout issue - How to handle

Tags: jdbc, jboss, db2

This may have been asked numerous times but none of them helped me so far.

Here's some **history**:

- QueryTimeOut: 120 secs
- Database:DB2
- App Server: JBoss
- Framework: Struts 2

I've one query which fetches around a million records. Yes, we need to fetch it all at once for caching purpose, sadly can't change the design.
Now, we've 2 servers Primary and DR. In DR server, the query is getting executed within 30 secs, so no timeout issue there. But in Primary serverit is getting time out due to some unknown reason. Sometimes it is getting timed out in `rs.next()` and sometime in `pstmt.executeQuery()`.
All DB **indexes**, **connection pool** etc are in place. The explain plan shows, there are no full table scan as well.

**My Analysis:**

Since query is not the issue here, there might be issue in Network delay? 
How can I get the root cause behind this timeout. How can I make sure there are no connection leakage? (Since all connection are closed properly).
Any way to recover from the timeout and again execute the query with increased timeout value for e.g: `pstmt.setQueryTimeOut(600)`? <- Note that this has no effect whatsoever. Don't know why..!

Appreciate any inputs.

Thank You!

Comment: I'm assuming Primary and DR have roughly the same hardware and table sizes?  What kind of other work is happening on Primary (lots of other connections, etc)?  If this is a read-only query, are you using a transaction?  The db should throw a different error if the network connection itself timed out (or rather, your driver should).  You probably need to post your query/application code.

Comment: Yes, both are more or less having same hardware/software configurations. There are a lot of other application which are accessing this particular database as well. Yes this is an read-only query (I'll try to paste the skeleton of the query since It is a secured app and I don't want to mess things up exposing the exact query :) )

Comment: Also, for getting the db connection we are using our own Database Manager framework which is supposed to handle all the opening and closing the connections.